# jQuery allow only number or decimal point or percentage sign

Tags: javascript, jquery

i just want to allow value like below to pass:

18
12.5%
13%

not allowing any other like:
12ad
aa21

```js
if( /[0-9\.]+%?/.test( shop_price ) == true){      
    $("#shop_price_label").html("Please enter number or number % only")
    event.preventDefault();
```

but its not working with the above code. can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the line start(`^`) and line end(`$`) notations also

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?%?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/otNcltuzb-gJRUdx)